# nextjs dynamic routing linking

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dynamic-routing

I have nested dynamic routes in my app, here is the folder structure:

[image]

Here is a preview of my page (/helpa/business/common-questions):
[image]

Because of seo optimalizations, when the user click the Open and manage a shop subtab, I want to navigate the user to the same url only space replaced with -.

```
  <Link
                href={`${maintablist[maintab]
                  .replace(/\s/g, '-')
                  .toLowerCase()}/${subtablist[0]
                  .replace(/\s/g, '-')
                  .toLowerCase()}`}
              >
```

But when the user click this link, the url will also include the dynamic folder name, which is I don't know why, how can I remove it (without writing custom to replace that...)

> http://localhost:3000/en/helpa/[maincategory]/business/open-and-manage-a-shop/

What is the problem with my code, why is that dynamic name injected in the url, maybe I missed something with dynamic routes linking?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I just figured it out:

```
<Link
                      href="/helpa/[maincategory]/[subcategory]"
                      as={
                        '/helpa/' +
                        `${maintablist[maintab]
                          .replace(/\s/g, '-')
                          .toLowerCase()}/${item
                          .replace(/\s/g, '-')
                          .toLowerCase()}`
                      }
                >
```

This way you specify the dynamic parameters in your url